# Error: [object Object] when i try to post my username and password in a rest service in angular

Tags: angular, rest, http-post, angular-services

Written my code in angular cli with the help of sublime text editor and node.js
my login component looks like logincomponent.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule,NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticateService } from '../services/authenticate.service';
import { Login } from './login-model';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {     
    log:any={}; 
    data:any;
    res:any;


  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router,private authenticate:AuthenticateService ) { 
   this.log = new Login(this.log.username,this.log.password)
  }

  ngOnInit() {  


  }
  onClick(){ 
    console.log("clicked");      
    this.authenticate.loginvalidate (this.log).subscribe((res) =>{console.log(res);});
}
}
```

i got error when i try to post the data to the rest api its shows error like Error: Error [object][object]

```
//service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response,RequestOptions,Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
import { Login } from '../login/login-model';


import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AuthenticateService {
res:any;
constructor(private http: Http, private jsonp:Jsonp) { }

   loginvalidate(user){
    let url = 'http://localhost:9000/EzeeShipping_Java/userlogin';
    const body = JSON.stringify({username:user.username,password:user.password });

   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

    return this.http.post(url,body,options).map(res=>res.json());
 }
}
```

my rest service s running in a tomcat server
i dont know y i didnt get a json data as a response
kindly help me out

login.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-area">  
        <form #userform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClick(userform)" >
        <br style="clear:both">
                    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Login Form</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required [(ngModel)]="log.username" >

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Password" required [(ngModel)]="log.password">
                    </div>



        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" [disabled]="userform.invalid">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="test()">Test</button></div>
</div>
```

this is my login.component.html file

Login-model.ts

```
export class Login{
    public username:string;
    public password:string;

    constructor(u:string,p:string){
    this.username = u;
    this.password = p;

    }


}
```

Comment: Use `user` directly instead of `body`. There is no need to do `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: are you able to get more information for the error? You need to view the contents of the objects that are being logged to see what they contain.

Comment: when i use user also it gives the same error

Comment: return this.http.post(url,user,options).map(res=>res.json()); it gives the same object object error

Comment: @senthil the username and password value come from html forms right ?

Comment: yes it comes from the form

Comment: Can you update html and model code in this question ?

Comment: updated sir    i am trying to clear the error upto 3days i cant solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    log: Login = new Login();
    data: any;
    res: any;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticate: AuthenticateService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    onClick() {
        console.log("clicked");
        this.authenticate.loginvalidate(this.log).subscribe((res) => { console.log(res); });
    }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
loginvalidate(user) {
    let url = 'http://localhost:9000/EzeeShipping_Java/userlogin';
    const body = user;

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(url, body, options).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: declare log like this : log: Login = new Login();

Comment: no error in log dude i have console.log in servicen and getting the output what i have typed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing res as a Response Object and remove content type Json and add below one

```
 private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

return this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(user),{headers:this.headers}).map((res:Response)=>res.json());
//Import Response from http
import {Response,ResponseContentType} from '@angular/http';

Remove this line from constructor and pass this.log directly
this.log = new Login(this.log.username,this.log.password)
```

Comment: same error occurs dude  can u send me a syntax for http.post with sending 2parameters

Comment: Updated the solution..just try it

Comment: help me out bro

Comment: E:/Virtuous Solutions/userscreen/USERSCREEN/src/app/services/authenticate.service.ts (25,61): Cannot find name 'headers'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.headers'?